# Swift Get Generic Type of Array

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, types, dynamictype

I need to get the generic type of an array.

I have an object that is an `Array<Decodable>`, but I am not guaranteed that the generic type is always `Decodable`. I know I can get the type of the thing by saying `array.self.dynamicType` to get the `Array.Type`, but I need something like `array.generic.self.dynamicType` to get `Decodable.Type`. How would I do this?

Comment: How did you get only `Array.Type` to print? [`print([1, 2, 3].dynamicType)` yields `Array<Int>`](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57ebf024ad13d8063ad09cfc), not just `Array`. If you expect quality answers, you'll have to give use a more [concrete, minimal, complete, and verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Yeah it does give Array<Int>, but that is of Array.Type. Should have clarified better. That seems irrelevant though, given that I don't care about that piece. I just want the generic type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend `Array` with a computed property that exposes its generic type parameter `Element`:

```
extension Array {
    var ElementType: Element.Type {
        return Element.self
    }
}

print([1, 2, 3].dynamicType) //Array<Int>
print([1, 2, 3].ElementType) //Int
```

Comment: I'll give this a shot. Looks like it could do what I need.

Comment: It certainly works, but I'm still searching for a better way

Comment: Ran into a issue with casting too, which I kind of have to do. If you've got thoughts I'd appreciate them. Posted a new questions, since technically this answer this questions just fine. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39753881/determine-object-type-of-array-element-parameter