# Determine Object Type of Array Element Parameter

Tags: arrays, swift, casting, dynamictype

Put a playground below that shows my issue and it's output. I need to write a method you can pass `AnyObject?` into, then determine the type of that object. If it's an array, I'll also need to determine it's Element type. This works fine before the method is called, but after I can't get at the types. Specifically, the element type doesn't come back proper due to casting.

Playground

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import Foundation

extension Array {
    var ElementType: Element.Type {
        return Element.self
    }
}

class tester {
    static func test(array:AnyObject?){
        print("ATYPE: ", array.dynamicType)
        print("ATYPE Good: ", array!.dynamicType)
        print("ETYPE: ", (array as! Array<AnyObject>).ElementType)
    }
}

let myArray: Array<NSString> = []
print("ATYPE ORIG: ", myArray.dynamicType)
print("ETYPE ORIG: ", myArray.ElementType)
tester.test(myArray)
```

Output

```
"ATYPE ORIG:  Array<NSString>\n"
"ETYPE ORIG:  NSString\n"

"ATYPE:  Optional<AnyObject>\n"
"ATYPE Good:  Array<NSString>\n"
"ETYPE:  AnyObject\n"
```

Comment: Casting to `Array<AnyObject>` erases your types. You'll need to маке `test` a generic function. I'm working on my answer right now. BTW, Swift allows top level functions. It's preferable to static members in arbitrary classes like `tester`. This isn't Java ;)

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Awesome. I'll be waiting for your answer then. Haven't done much with the minimal swift reflection stuff. How did you know I was taught on java back in the day!? lol

Comment: Forcing static code that doesn't make any sense to be associated to a type to be associated to a type for the arbitrary pursuit of object orientation is a dead giveaway for Java :p

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Yeah. I kinda just slammed the playground together really quick for this question. Good catch.

Comment: @stevennorris I have an idea in mind for how to do this, but I can't quite figure it out yet. I"ll ask my own question on the matter, and see how it goes

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov Thanks. I'm playing with generics now, but can't seem to get anything quite like I need it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124456/discussion-between-alexander-momchliov-and-steventnorris).